# Capacitor and hydraulic analogy

Tags: capacitance

Would anyone kindly explain me the hydraulic analogy for the working of a capacitor w.r.t the article of wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor...  Help!!

Answer (score 4):

The analogy of a system of water pipes to represent an electrical circuit is well established and actually very useful, especially at elementary schools. Pressure = voltage and rate of water flow = current. Switches can be modelled as valves and resistors as restrictions in the pipe.

Anyhow, the hydraulic analogy of a capacitor can be though of as a rubber membrane that exerts a pressure proportional to the amount it's been stretched i.e. how much water you've pumped into it:

$$ \text{Pressure} = \frac{\text{vol of water}}{K} $$

for some constant $K$. This has an obvious similarity to the equation for the voltage on a  capacitor:

$$ V = \frac{Q}{C} $$

where the charge $Q$ is represented by the volume of water and the constant $K$ represents the capacitance.